# jQuery custom validate option

Tags: jquery, validation

Is there a way to validate a form instead of rules?

For example:

In the form there are 3 check boxes; 
i want to test if none of them is selected -
in which case, return false and prevent the form from submitting

Comment: Are you using the [validation plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

Answer (score 0):

HTML :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="event[]" id="event" value="click">click<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="event[]" id="event" value="focus">focus<br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="event[]" id="event" value="change">change<br>
```

jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    $("form").submit(function() 
    { 
       var checked = $("input[@id=event]:checked").length; 
        if (checked == 0) 
        { 
            alert ("Please select at least one event"); 
            return false; 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

Please do above steps and let me know if any.

Comment: is there a way to integrate this inside validate plugin
 $("#adminform").validate({
   errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
   error.appendTo( element.parent().next() );
    },   
  rules:{
   max_upload:{
        required:true,
                 number:true
            }
             
  }
 });

Comment: Not likely, it would take the extending of the plugin itself in order to include such custom validations.

Answer (score 0):

```
         submitHandler: function(form) {

        if ( $('input[type="radio"]').is(':checked')==true){
            form.submit() ;  
        }else{
            alert("Please choose option");
        }
     }
```